# Get list of Dates based on conditions via SQL

Tags: mysql

Currently having a little difficulty with respect to getting a list of dates.

I currently have the following SQL:

```
SELECT DISTINCT DATE(startDate) activity_date
              , CASE WHEN (DATE(endDate) - DATE(startDate)) > 0 THEN DATE(endDate) ELSE FALSE END multiEvent 
           FROM activities 
          WHERE startdate BETWEEN '2017-08-01' AND '2017-08-31'  
            AND accountid = 578 
          ORDER 
             BY DATE(startdate)
```

Which gives the following result:

```
activity_date | multiEvent
2017-08-07    | 0
2017-08-07    | 2017-08-10
2017-08-18    | 0
```

However, what i am trying to achieve is, if multiEvent is not zero, then list the dates between the dates of activity_date & multiEvent into a single column.

Result I am trying to achieve:

```
activity_date | 
2017-08-07    | 
2017-08-07    |
2017-08-08    |
2017-08-09    |
2017-08-10    | 
2017-08-18    |
```

ideas? :)

Comment: mysql or sql-server?

Comment: SqlZim - mySQL - just updated :)

Comment: shameless plug: I wrote an article on this. https://www.plumislandmedia.net/mysql/filling-missing-data-sequences-cardinal-integers/  Good news: it's possible.  Bad news: it isn't tremendously easy.

Comment: Consider handling issues of data display in application code.

Comment: @O.Jones Just glad you didn't go with 'pen island'

Comment: @Strawberry I don't live on "pen island."  :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to first find a way to create rows for dates between `activity_date` and `multiEvent`. This query will produce the intended resultset of dates, as individual rows.

```
  select date(eachDate) as eachDate from  
  (select adddate('1970-01-01',t4.i*10000 + t3.i*1000 + t2.i*100 + t1.i*10 + t0.i) as eachDate 
  from   
  (select 0 i union select 1 union select 2 union select 3 union select 4 union select 5 union select 6 union select 7 union select 8 union select 9) t0,  
  (select 0 i union select 1 union select 2 union select 3 union select 4 union select 5 union select 6 union select 7 union select 8 union select 9) t1,   
  (select 0 i union select 1 union select 2 union select 3 union select 4 union select 5 union select 6 union select 7 union select 8 union select 9) t2,   
  (select 0 i union select 1 union select 2 union select 3 union select 4 union select 5 union select 6 union select 7 union select 8 union select 9) t3,   
  (select 0 i union select 1 union select 2 union select 3 union select 4 union select 5 union select 6 union select 7 union select 8 union select 9) t4) as v   
  where  
  eachDate between date('2017-08-07')
  and date('2017-08-10') order by eachDate asc ;
```

This will produce a result like

```
eachDate
2017-08-07
2017-08-08
2017-08-09
2017-08-10
```

Now, we need to fit in the above query with your existing query to get the intended output. The query would look something like this.

```
  select 
  activity_date 
  from 
  (select 
  date(startDate) as activity_date
  from
  activities 
  where 
  startdate between date('2017-08-01') and date('2017-08-31')  
  and accountid = 578 
  and NOT (DATE(endDate) - DATE(startDate)) > 0
  union all
  select 
  eachDate 
  from 
  (select date(eachDate) as eachDate 
  from  
  (select adddate('1970-01-01',t4.i*10000 + t3.i*1000 + t2.i*100 + t1.i*10 + t0.i) as eachDate  
  from   
  (select 0 i union select 1 union select 2 union select 3 union select 4 union select 5 union select 6 union select 7 union select 8 union select 9) t0,  
  (select 0 i union select 1 union select 2 union select 3 union select 4 union select 5 union select 6 union select 7 union select 8 union select 9) t1,   
  (select 0 i union select 1 union select 2 union select 3 union select 4 union select 5 union select 6 union select 7 union select 8 union select 9) t2,   
  (select 0 i union select 1 union select 2 union select 3 union select 4 union select 5 union select 6 union select 7 union select 8 union select 9) t3,   
  (select 0 i union select 1 union select 2 union select 3 union select 4 union select 5 union select 6 union select 7 union select 8 union select 9) t4) as v   
  where  
  eachDate between date('2017-08-01')
  and date('2017-08-31')) as dates_table
  join
  (select 
  date(startDate) as startDate,
  date(endDate) as endDate
  from
  activities 
  where 
  startdate between date('2017-08-01') and date('2017-08-31')  
  and accountid = 578 
  and (date(endDate) - date(startDate)) > 0 ) as activities_table
  on dates_table.eachDate between activities_table.startDate and activities_table.endDate) as main
  order by 
  main.activity_date asc;
```

and the output looks like this.

```
activity_date
2017-08-07
2017-08-07
2017-08-08
2017-08-09
2017-08-10
2017-08-18
```

Comment: @sammy-sung check this query.

Comment: Giving me an error. On line "  and NOT (DATE(endDate) - DATE(startDate)) > 0
" is missing a bracket, but even this does not fix the issue even after declaring an alias.

Comment: aliases shouldn't be an issue here.